# Why dovecot 2.2.13 is not moving emails from new/ to cur/?

Tags: dovecot, gentoo

I am using dovecot 2.2.13 on gentoo 64bit.

When new email arrives it stays in new/ directory instead to be moved to cur/ directory.
I read that `maildir_empty_new = yes` was added to `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` but that is not working. 
Do I have to uncomment something else as well in order this to work (or comment something else)?

This is important to me because dovecot-uidlist is updated with next UID only when I check new email with my mail client. I have some procmail pipe script and I need next uid (which i am getting by parsing dovecot-uidlist).

Maybe I can use `doveadm` along with my pipe script in order to move from new/ to cur/ and then update dovecot-uidlist.

This is my `dovecot -n`:

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.16.5-gentoo x86_64 Gentoo Base System release 2.2
auth_mechanisms = plain login digest-md5
first_valid_gid = 500
last_valid_gid = 2000
last_valid_uid = 2000
login_greeting = Santa server is ready.
mail_gid = vmail
mail_location = /var/vmail/%d/%n/:INDEX=/var/vmail/%d/%n/indexes
mail_uid = vmail
maildir_empty_new = yes
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave duplicate
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/dovecot/server.in.crt
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/dovecot/server.csr.rapid
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/dovecot/server.key.rapid
ssl_key_password = pass
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found this on dovecot website:

> ~/Maildir/new, ~/Maildir/cur and ~/Maildir/tmp directories contain the
>   messages for INBOX. The tmp directory is used during delivery, new
>   messages arrive in new and read shall be moved to cur by the clients.

So it seams that moving new message to cur is not default dovecot behaviour.

It would be great if I could somehow do that manually then but with update of dovecot-uidlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use maildir format, you need to specify that in your configuration.  Try changing:

```
mail_location = /var/vmail/%d/%n/:INDEX=/var/vmail/%d/%n/indexes
```

to:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/:INDEX=/var/vmail/%d/%n/indexes
```

I use procmail with MAILDIR specified as `$HOME/Maildir/`.  Mail is delivered to `$HOME/Maildir/new` with names like `1417748317.25141_1.myhost`.  When I pick mail up dovecot move them to `$HOME/Maildir/new` and appends `:2,` to the filename.  When the file is read flags are appended.  I don't need to know dovecot's uid to handle the messages.  I have procmail filtering mail into other mailboxes, and those are handled well without knowing dovecot's UIDs for that folder.

Comment: nothing. same thing. email are still in new/ .

Comment: take a look at update

Comment: maybe is I can somehow use /usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver ..... but I am not sure about that. Something like cd /var/vmail/domain/user/new

for i in *; do /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver  -d user < $i; rm -f
$i; echo "Message $i"; done

Comment: @pregmatch Not sure why you need to worry about Dovecot UID in procmail.  Procmail's default processing works well with Dovecot.  See my edit.

Comment: i need uid because i want to put parsed email to db along with uid. so if i list emails from db i need value in checkbox for uid.